# ScrollView not scrolling all the way down

Tags: android, scrollview

I'm using a scrollview in my app as follows. But bottom part of the screen is not completely visible, even when I have scrolled down as far as possible. What am I doing wrong or is there a way to fix this?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:orientation="vertical"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button    
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
      />  

   <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

      <LinearLayout    
        android:orientation="vertical"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >  

                <TableLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

                    <TableRow> 
                    <TextView 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:text="name">
                    </TextView>
                    <EditText 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        >
                    </EditText>
                    </TableRow> </TableLayout>   </LinearLayout> </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Scrollview does't go down until the last item at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: I dont know why some people show interest in negativevoting and commenting instead of answering.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 scrollview.scrollTo(0, scrollview.getBottom());
```

Answer (score 0):

Once I had the same issue
You can set scroll position at bottom by 
`scrollview.scrollTo(0, scrollview.getBottom());` 
 if it is not working, i think the problem is with your `AVD`, so make change your `AVD`'s screen size  by `Android SDK and AVD Manager`. Select Your AVD and start it with checking `Scaledisplay to real size` to appropriate size.